# CSS: Dejar de aplicar estilos a partir de cierta anchura

Tags: css, bootstrap

El problema que tengo es que he usado una plantilla de bootstrap y he modificado parte del CSS.

Entonces lo tengo responsive desde 1920px a 1024px, pero a partir de 992 los estilos cambian mucho y se lía todo, entonces me gustaría a partir de 1024 aplicarle scroll horizontal:

```
body{min-width: 1024px;
     position:relative;}
```

Me gustaría que todos los estilos desde 1024px al mínimo no se aplicaran, que únicamente se aplicara el scroll horizontal.

Comment: ¿Entiendo que los estilos CSS los has cambiado de inicio en el menú de la página de Bootstrap antes de descargarlo o los has ido solapando con !important?

Comment: Los he ido modificado en otro archivo, he creado clases por lo cual no me ha dado muchos problemas y si me lo daba usaba !important, sí.

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar el orden en el que has establecido los estilos? Me explico, a la hora de importar los ficheros .css cual has puesto más arriba y cual has indicado más abajo.

Answer (score 5):

Utiliza los media queries:

```
@media max-width: 1023px{
  //Aplicar estilos que quieras       
  body {
    //Estilos
  }
}
```

De modo que para pantallas menores a 1024px muestren los css que quieras.

Comment: La idea es que no tenga que aplicar todos los estilos de nuevo, simplemente que a partir de ese media query no aplique ninguno..

Comment: Entonces busca los @media de bootstrap y elimina/comenta los que no te interesen.

Answer (score 3):

Reutilizando la respuesta de @Camilo.

Tienes que usar los `@media` que proporciona css.

Con ellos podras:

- Definir estilos para diferentes tamaños de pantalla (ejemplo al final de esta respuesta).

  - Utiliza @min-width y @max-width para definir los [intervalos de tamaños](http://librosweb.es/foro/pregunta/184/medidas-recomendadas-para-los-media-queries-de-css/) {Es recomendable que te orientes con tamaños de pantallas realies y sus posibilidades.
- Definir estilos para diferentes visualizaciones! Esta claro que si preparas una pagina para imprimir no deberia verse igual que en el navegador.

  - Puedes colocar print o screen por ejemplo.

Echale un vistazo a este apartado de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Te dejo un ejemplo practico con cambio de tamaños y colores.

```css
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

/*mobile-portrait: min:320px - max:479px;*/

@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:479px) {
  div{
    width:15%;
    height:15%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:red;
  }
}

/*mobile-landscape: min:480px - max:599px;*/

@media (min-width:480px) and (max-width:599px) {
  div{
    width:30%;
    height:30%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:green;
  }
}

/*small-tablet-portrait: min:600px - max:799px;*/

@media (min-width:600px) and (max-width:799px) {
  div{
    width:45%;
    height:45%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:pink;
  }
}

/*small-tablet-landscape: min:800px - max:767px;*/

@media (min-width:800px) and (max-width:767px) {
  div{
    width:60%;
    height:60%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:blue;
  }
}

/*tablet-portrait: min:768px - max:1023px;*/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px) {
  div{
    width:75%;
    height:75%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
}

/*tablet-landscape: min:1024px;*/

@media (min-width:1024px) {
  div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color:orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Etiam quis quam. Integer lacinia. Nulla est. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat. Maecenas lorem. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Etiam sapien elit, consequat eget, tristique non, venenatis quis, ante. Fusce wisi. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl. Fusce eget urna. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. Nulla quis diam. Ut tempus purus at lorem.</p>
    <p>Morbi a metus. Phasellus enim erat, vestibulum vel, aliquam a, posuere eu, velit. Nullam sapien sem, ornare ac, nonummy non, lobortis a, enim. Nunc tincidunt ante vitae massa. Duis ante orci, molestie vitae, vehicula venenatis, tincidunt ac, pede. Nulla accumsan, elit sit amet varius semper, nulla mauris mollis quam, tempor suscipit diam nulla vel leo. Etiam commodo dui eget wisi. Donec iaculis gravida nulla. Donec quis nibh at felis congue commodo. Etiam bibendum elit eget erat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes utilizar los `media queries` que provee `css`

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 992px){
    /* Acá todos tus selectores con sus respectivas propiedades y valores */
}
```

Definición de conceptos:

`max-width` = Todas las resoluciones menores al tamaño especificado

`min-width` = Todas las resoluciones mayores al tamaño especificado

Espero te sirva, saludos !